# Function to round a float to nearest float with specific allowed decimals

Tags: c++, math, rounding

I'm trying to write a function that behaves like the following (c++, but answers in any language accepted)

```
float roundToGivenDecimals(float input, float allowedDecimals[])
```

usage:

```
float roundToGivenDecimals(10.4, [0.1, 0.45, 0.67, 0.80, 0.99]) // output: 10.45
float roundToGivenDecimals(3.15, [0.1, 0.45, 0.67, 0.80, 0.99]) // output: 3.15
float roundToGivenDecimals(3.01, [0.1, 0.45, 0.67, 0.80, 0.99]) // output: 2.99
```

Similar to a standard round() method, but with only specific fractional values allowed

I've been thinking this over for a while but I'm struggling to come up with a nice solution, any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This function is called `std::binary_search`.

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to see how std::binary_search fixes this on its own, would I not have to create an array with the decimal values for the entire range I wanted? what if My range of values went from 0 > 1000?

i.e. 0.1, 0.45, 0.67, 0.80, 0.99, 1.1, 1.45, 1.65, [....], 999.99

Comment: Subtract the fractional part of `input` from every element in `allowedDecimals` and find the position of the minimum absolute value in the resulting array.  Bob, as we say, is your mother's brother.

Comment: This sounds very promising, I'll give it a go and report back

Comment: Sorry I always forget that binary_search is totally useless... You need std::lower_bound actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel Davies, I changed a bit your answer, now it works correctly:

```
double roundToGivenDecimals(double input, double allowedDecimals[], int numAllowedDecimals) {
    double inputFractional = input - floor(input);
    double result = input;
    double minDiff = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numAllowedDecimals; ++i) {
        if (fabs(inputFractional - allowedDecimals[i]) < minDiff) {
            result = floor(input) + allowedDecimals[i];
        } else if (fabs(inputFractional + 1 - allowedDecimals[i]) < minDiff) {
            result = floor(input) - 1 + allowedDecimals[i];
        }
        minDiff = fabs(input - result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks, this is a neat solution

Answer (score 0):

following @High Performance Marks suggestion I have created the following:

```
float roundToGivenDecimals(float input, float allowedDecimals[], int numAllowedDecimals) {
    double inputIntegral;
    double inputFractional; 
    inputFractional = modf(input, &inputIntegral);

    float minAbsValue;
    int minAbsValueIndex;

    for(int i = 0; i < numAllowedDecimals; i++) {
        float allowedDecimalMinusFractional = allowedDecimals[i] - inputFractional;
        float absVal = abs(allowedDecimalMinusFractional);
        if (absVal < minAbsValue || i == 0) {
            minAbsValue = absVal;
            minAbsValueIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return inputIntegral + allowedDecimals[minAbsValueIndex];
}
```

This is mostly correct and works for my purposes, but there are eventualities where this function does not behave as intended:

```
float roundToGivenDecimals(10.4, [0.1, 0.45, 0.67, 0.80, 0.99]) // output: 10.45 correct
float roundToGivenDecimals(3.15, [0.1, 0.45, 0.67, 0.80, 0.99]) // output: 3.15 correct
float roundToGivenDecimals(3.01, [0.1, 0.45, 0.67, 0.80, 0.99]) // output: 3.1 <-- this is incorrect, the expected output should be 2.99
```